# Why does the assignment of values to keys in identical, but differently created nested dictionaries leads to different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, dictionary-comprehension

Code snippets are worth a thousand words, so here they are:

```
# Creation of data_dict1
data_types = ('abnormal', 'normal')
data_dict1 = dict.fromkeys(data_types, {0: {}, 1: {}})
# Creation of data_dict2
data_dict2 = data_dict2 = {'abnormal': {0: {}, 1: {}}, 'normal': {0: {}, 1: {}}}

# Check
print(data_dict1)
print(data_dict2)
print(data_dict1 == data_dict2)

>>> {'abnormal': {0: {}, 1: {}}, 'normal': {0: {}, 1: {}}}
>>> {'abnormal': {0: {}, 1: {}}, 'normal': {0: {}, 1: {}}}
>>> True
```

As you can see, the nested dictionaries **data_dict1** and **data_dict2** are identical regardless of their methods of creation.
But when I assign values in the same way, I get different results:

```
data_dict1['abnormal'][0]['result'] = 'abnormal_0'
data_dict1['abnormal'][1]['result'] = 'abnormal_1'
data_dict1['normal'][0]['result'] = 'normal_0'
data_dict1['normal'][1]['result'] = 'normal_1'

data_dict2['abnormal'][0]['result'] = 'abnormal_0'
data_dict2['abnormal'][1]['result'] = 'abnormal_1'
data_dict2['normal'][0]['result'] = 'normal_0'
data_dict2['normal'][1]['result'] = 'normal_1'

# Check
print(data_dict1)
print(data_dict2)
print(data_dict1 == data_dict2)

>>> {'abnormal': {0: {'result': 'normal_0'}, 1: {'result': 'normal_1'}}, 'normal': {0: {'result': 'normal_0'}, 1: {'result': 'normal_1'}}}
>>> {'abnormal': {0: {'result': 'abnormal_0'}, 1: {'result': 'abnormal_1'}}, 'normal': {0: {'result': 'normal_0'}, 1: {'result': 'normal_1'}}}
>>> False
```

The values for **data_dict1['abnormal'][0]['result']** and **data_dict1['abnormal'][0]['result']** are **'normal_0'** and **'normal_1'**, respectively, and not **'abnormal_0'** and **'abnormal_1'** as they should be. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is coming about due to the way you initiate `data_dict1`.

```
data_dict1 = dict.fromkeys(data_types, {0: {}, 1: {}})
```

When you do this, both of the keys in `data_dict1` are set to the same nested dictionary. This means that after these lines:

```
data_dict1['abnormal'][0]['result'] = 'abnormal_0'
data_dict1['abnormal'][1]['result'] = 'abnormal_1'
```

The value of both keys in the dictionary, `abnormal` and `normal` is changed. If we check `data_dict1` at this point, we see:

```
>>> data_dict1
{'abnormal': {0: {'result': 'abnormal_0'}, 1: {'result': 'abnormal_1'}},
 'normal': {0: {'result': 'abnormal_0'}, 1: {'result': 'abnormal_1'}}}
```

When we continue to then change the value of the `normal` key, the same thing happens, giving us the result you have found.

We can check that both nested dictionaries are actually the same dictionary in memory by using `is`:

```
>>> data_dict1['abnormal'] is data_dict1['normal']
True
```

You have initiated `data_dict2` by actually assigning different nested dictionaries to the keys, and we can see that this is true in the same way as above:

```
>>> data_dict2['abnormal'] is data_dict2['normal']
False
```

We can avoid this behaviour, without having to type it out like you did in `data_dict2`. One way to do this would be to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> data_types = ('abnormal', 'normal')
>>> data_dict1 = {k: {0: {}, 1: {}} for k in data_types}
>>> data_dict1['abnormal'] is data_dict1['normal']
False
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very clear. So what is the point of using the function fromkeys() to create a nested dictionary like I did for data_dict1? Is there a way to efficiently initialize nested dictionaries without having to do it like I did for data_dict2?